# AWS CFT template IAM Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm using CFT to create an IAM policy that allows access to only one S3 bucket alone (which is also created in the same CFT itself). Here is the part of the CFT where the problem lies

```
    {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "BucketCreation":{
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
               "BucketName":"samplebucket",
              }
            },
        "IAMPolicy":{
          "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
          "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": "ListS3BucketsPolicy",
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Statement": [{
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:*"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "BucketCreation" , "Arn" ]
                }]
             }
          }
       } 
    } 
  }
```

Now the above cft creates a IAM policy with a resource statement `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"` well this gives only bucket access and not object level access. What I need is the resource section to look like this `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"`.Is this possible in CFT?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html)

> You can use wildcards as part of the resource ARN. You can use
>   wildcard characters (* and ?) within any ARN segment (the parts
>   separated by colons). An asterisk (*) represents any combination of
>   zero or more characters, and a question mark (?) represents any single
>   character. You can use multiple * or ? characters in each segment, but
>   a wildcard cannot span segments.
>
> This ARN uses the wildcard * in the relative-ID part of the ARN to
>   identify all objects in the example bucket.

**Update:**
To concatinate `/*` look at [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) like [Join](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html)

Comment: ok I think you didn't get my question right. I asked how can we do it through CFT ? The link you provided tells what "*" does in a IAM polilcy. That's not my question. My question is simple In the CFT `"Resource": "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "BucketCreation" , "Arn" ]` This line will get the bucket's arn i.e `arn:aws:s3:::bucketname` but I want `arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*` How to get it through CFT? Like say should we give like this `"Resource": "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "BucketCreation" , "Arn" ]/*` or some other way? [P.S. The method I used here is for example purpose and it wont work]

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @titogeo. I've found the solution.Here it is

```
    {
     "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
     "Resources": {
        "BucketCreation":{
           "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
           "Properties": {
              "BucketName":"samplebucket"
             }
          },
        "IAMPolicy":{
          "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
          "Properties": {
             "PolicyName": "ListS3BucketsPolicy",
             "PolicyDocument": {
                 "Statement": [{
                     "Effect": "Allow",
                     "Action": [
                         "s3:*"
                      ],
                  "Resource":{ 
                      "Fn::Join":["",[
                                       {
                                         "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "BucketCreation" , "Arn" ]
                                        },
                                       "/*"
                                      ]
                                  ]
                             }
                        }]
                     }
                 }
             } 
         }

     }
```

P.S: Sorry for the poor indendation. I'm Frustrated with it, if someone could fix it, that would be helpful.